# retain line break on textarea client side

Tags: php, mysql

I know there's mysql method to keep line break but I want to format it before in go into server side.

So when user enter new line on the textarea, how do I 'preserve' it when it's passed to PHP variable?

```
//form
..
<textarea name="message" maxlength="100" id="textarea"></textarea>

$message = $_POST["message"];
```

Comment: use `nl2br()` then.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `$message = nl2br($_POST["message"]);` just like that? Don't need to do anything on client side?

Comment: that is pretty much it. See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- can I do trim together with that?

Comment: Hm.... I think you can, yet the way they're combined might be important. When in doubt, `nl2br` first, then `trim()`, or vice-versa. Yet, am pretty sure you could combine them. I can't remember if I ever tried that before, to be perfectly honest.

Comment: The line breaks aren't lost when passed to PHP, but they aren't visible when displayed unless you display them using **nl2br** when they are selected out of the database.  To verify that the newlines are there, you can use view source or display them on an HTML page in a **<pre>** block.  Don't store the **<br>**s in the database, they waste space and may make future formatting more difficult.

Comment: @user2182349 roger that! so in the db it will be still \n if I don't display it using `nl2br`?

Comment: Yes, it will keep the **\n** in the database, and you would use **nl2br** when displaying it.